# Problema con mixing básico en sass y sintaxis scss

Tags: html, css3, sass, scss

Hola tengo el siguiente código,estoy practicando los mixins de sass con la sintaxis scss(por que soy medio bruto y con tabulaciones me pierdo xD),se supone que de esa manera es la forma de crear el mixin o no?,espero me puedan ayudar.

```
@mixin colores($fondo,$articulo);{


}

    body {
        background: $fondo;
}

articulo{
    background: $articulo;
}

@include colores(#ff8000,#fff);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código contiene un par de errores:

1. Le sobra un punto y coma (`;`) en el mixin antes de la llave
2. Para que se aplique las variables en las reglas, debes incluirlas dentro del mixin (ahora mismo tienes un mixin vacío).

Solucionando esas dos cosas, el código quedaría así:

```
@mixin colores($fondo,$articulo){

  body {
    background: $fondo;
  }

  articulo{
    background: $articulo;
  }

}

@include colores(#ff8000,#fff);
```

Y el CSS generado sería éste:

```
body {
  background: #ff8000;
}

articulo {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: perfecto,quedo todo listo,me estaba rompiendo el craneo jajajaja